# Generating RSS feed from Ruby-on-Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rss, hyperlink

I have a Ruby on Rails online marketplace that is broken up into "categories". I want to be able to create RSS Feeds for each category, every time a new listing is added.

The RSS should pull the listing's name and then provide a shortened hyperlink to that listing.

I'm a beginner in Ruby on Rails, what approach should I use to obtain this RS feed and how can I obtain a page's hyperlink, shorten it and integrate it into the feed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice video from Railscasts

http://railscasts.com/episodes/87-generating-rss-feeds

Comment: The original doesn't, the revised one does.